# ClientHttp Vs BrowserHTTP Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I want to know what are the pros and cons of using the ClientHttp and BrowserHTTP.

Answer (score 1):

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) describes the differences in a table.

I can't easily reproduce the full table here, but some of the key differences that are worth mentioning, from my experience...

- The BrowserHttp stack is limited to GET and POST only, and status codes 200 and 404. This limits its use with well-behaved REST services.
- However, the BrowserHttp stack supports automatic cookie handling and the ClientHttp stack does not.

This may result in complications for line-of-business apps if your users initially authenticate through the browser (puts an Authorization cookie in the BrowserHttp cookie store) but then you use the ClientHttp stack because you want to use full-fidelity REST services; consequently your user will need to authenticate twice. The presence of load balancers that use cookies will also be problematic for the ClientHttp stack.